# Workflow or query on shouldChangeTextInRange UISearchBar method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am working on a scenario where when the user types a '$' as first character on search bar the system should add another $ after it, example: User types '$' and the system adds '$'so the text on search bar should look like '$$'.

I am implementing it as below:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text hasPrefix:@"$"])
    {
          text = [text stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
          self.searchBar.text = text;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Question**: How does the replacement text actually works? My understanding is that when user types '$', text parameter in the above method has '$' as value and that should get replaced with '$$' after the method is executed? But after executing this method I get '$$$' as the final string on search bar. However, if I return NO, for this method, I get '$$' on the search bar but then it prevents me to type anything else on the search bar.

Am I missing anything here? I am trying to understand how this method is actually working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried exactly what you're doing, but from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar%3ashouldChangeTextInRange%3areplacementText%3a) for that method it sounds like you should make a couple changes. First, you need to make sure there is one and only one $ in the text, otherwise every time you type a $ in the text field it's going to add an additional one. Second, did you try just changing the `text` parameter to @"$$" when that case is hit, instead of setting the value on the `searchBar.text` property? It seems to me that since you're returning YES from this method, you're telling the search bar to go ahead and change its text, but you're also changing it's text behind its back (by setting it directly).